# Как создать/повлиять на виджет из импортированного файла?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, qt-designer

Имеется основной файл с интерфейсом на *PyQt5*, в котором выполняется функция импорта другого **файла.py** с целью расширения функционала основного. 
К примеру, в основном файле имеется поле `QLabel`.

Требуется сделать так, чтобы при выполнении функции в импортируемом файле надпись `QLabel` первого менялась.

**Основной файл**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import importlib


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.load_plugin)

    def load_plugin(self):
        import_plugin = importlib.import_module("import_plugin", ".")
        plugin_class = import_plugin.ImportPluginClass()
        plugin_class.print()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Импортируемый файл**:

```
from untitled_ui import *


class ImportPluginClass:
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImportPluginClass, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()


    def print(self):
        print("!!!")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше объясните какой модуль вы запускаете, а какой модуль вы импортируете .

Comment: Основной файл.. Требуется в label поменять текст, создав функцию для этого в import_plugin.. В этом примере выводится принт 111 при нажатии на кнопку в основном файле.. Вопрос в том как повлиять на QLabel в main1, прописав в import_plugin что-то типа self.ui.label.setText("222")..

Comment: поправил код в изначальном посте

Comment: В это примере "!!!" выводится

Comment: Что такое `importlib.py`   ? Что такое `untitled_ui.py`   ?

Comment: советую, убрать все лишнее из примера, оставить только label если это возможно, ну или минимальное для воспроизведения, так же не должно быть непонятных импортов как указал выше @S.Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

**q1466499_main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from q1466499_importlib import ImportPluginClass


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.load_plugin)

    def load_plugin(self):
        self.import_plugin = ImportPluginClass()
        text = self.import_plugin._print()
        self.label.setText(text)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1466499_importlib.py**

```
class ImportPluginClass():
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImportPluginClass, self).__init__()
        pass
        
    def _print(self):
        return "Hello World!!!"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ! вроде все понятно, буду пробовать.

Comment: @ВладСавельев пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour